# JavaScript converting a decimal to an integer

Tags: javascript, php, integer, decimal

I Have a php variable..
`<?=number_format($total_commission,2)?>`
this has the value 
`£3,400.00`

I then have a JavaScript script which counts up to the value on the front-end

```
// Count Up
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var range = end - start;
  var minTimer = 50;
  var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
  // never go below minTimer
  stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);
  // get current time and calculate desired end time
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var endTime = startTime + duration;
  var timer;

  function run() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
    var value = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
    obj.innerHTML = value;
    if (value == end) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }

  timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
  run();

}

var value1 = <?=$total_count?>;
var value2 = <?=$total_commission?>;
var value3 = <?=$active_refs?>;

animateValue("value1", 0, value1, 1750);
animateValue("value2", 0, value2, 1750);
animateValue("value3", 0, value3, 1750);
```

The problem I am having is when the php variable is used in javascript it is converting the number to an integer and loosing the decimal values. How can I keep the number as a decimal when going from PHP to JavaScript?

I tried using toFixed(2) on the end variable but no luck..

Comment: "which counts up to the value on the front-end" You mean the JavaScript code is doing math on the number? Or is JavaScript just going to display the number as such in an animation?

Comment: @RuudHelderman Yes in an animation, but the JavaScript does do math to work out which number to count from, and too

Comment: Your PHP code is exposing a _formatted_ number to your JavaScript code. A formatted number is a _string_, not a number. You cannot do math on it. You should not even try.

Comment: Don't format the number in PHP, just leave it as it is and format it in JS after doing Math on it

Comment: `var value2 = "<?php echo $total_commission?>".replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')` should work, but like others have said, do math on the unformatted number from PHP.

Comment: for me this code cannot work, `animateValue` is an asynchronous function and it is applied 3 times at the same time, it is necessary to use the mechanism of promises

Comment: This line in your code converted the decimal to integer: `var value = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));` since `Math.round` function returns an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript you can try with using `Number()` function to convert a string to a number (integer or decimal) if needed, and you can use `parseFloat(number)` method.

Examples on using Number():

```
// Convert strings
Number('123'); // returns 123
Number('12.3'); // returns 12.3
Number('3.14someRandomStuff'); // returns NaN
Number('42px'); // returns NaN
```

Examples on using parseFloat():

```
var text = '3.14someRandomStuff';
var pointNum = parseFloat(text);
// returns 3.14
```

In your particular case however, this is how it could work as an example:
(Edited, updated code, using the OP's code, since I had a little more time now to clear this for later, useful reference)

```
<?php
$total_count = (string) "£3,400.00";
$total_commission = (string) "£3,500.25";
$active_refs = (string) "£4,400.87";
?>

<div class="container2">
  <div id="value1"></div>
  <div id="value2"></div>
  <div id="value3"></div>
</div>

<script>  

// getting a float number from a formatted PHP string
var getNum = function (str) {
    var num = str.replace(/[\£\,]/mg, '');
    var num2 = parseFloat(num);
    return num2;
}

// converting the counter value back to a currency format
var convertNum = function(number){
    let numb = number;
    return numb.toLocaleString('en-GB', {style : 'currency', currency : 'GBP', minimumFractionDigits : '2', currencyDisplay : 'symbol'});
}

var value1 = getNum("<?php echo (string) $total_count ?>");
var value2 = getNum("<?php echo (string) $total_commission ?>");
var value3 = getNum("<?php echo (string) $active_refs ?>");

// Count Up
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var range = end - start;
    var minTimer = 50;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    // never go below minTimer
    stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);
    // get current time and calculate desired end time
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var endTime = startTime + duration;
    var timer;

  function run() {
      var now = new Date().getTime();
      var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
      var value = parseFloat(end - (remaining * range));
      obj.innerHTML = convertNum(value);
      if (value == end) {
          clearInterval(timer);
      }
  }

  timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
  run();

}

animateValue("value1", 1, value1, 1750);
animateValue("value2", 1, value2, 1750);
animateValue("value3", 1, value3, 1750);

</script>
```

And you can also check the result/output of the above code version [here](http://main.xfiddle.com/462fc245/counter1.php):
or if it was deleted already, then [here](https://paiza.io/projects/8R6PsBARn7X0g_fvcGr5eA)

**And maybe less importantly** I’d like to point out that in your code the following line converted the decimal to integer which had to be edited too:

```
var value = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
```

This one line would return back an integer number.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you cant define variable with zeros after dot
1.**00**
Javascript engine clear all zeros in the end of numbers after dot.

examples:

```js
let oneZero = 1.0;
console.log('oneZero:',oneZero);
let twoZeros = 1.00;
console.log('twoZeros:',twoZeros);
let oneAndTen = 1.10;
console.log('1.10:',oneAndTen);
let threeZeros = 1.000;
console.log('threeZeros:',threeZeros)
```

For fix your problem you need just format like a string your number.

`let formatedString =  1+".00";`

But it's not best solution. You need use some like [numeraljs](http://numeraljs.com/) library